# Using Randomize Timer

Tags: vba, excel

What is wrong in below program code, why is it not returning the correct result?
Whenever I put any number in the cell (1,1) and run the program, numbers are changed automatically, also not throwing the correct result in cell (1,2).

```
Private Sub Sheet2_1()

    Dim num1 As Integer
    Dim grade As String

    Randomize Timer
    num1 = Int(Rnd * 100)

    Cells(1, 1).Value = num1

    If num1 >= 50 Then
        grade = "B"
        Cells(1, 2).Value = grade
    ElseIf num1 <= 100 And num1 > 50 Then
        grade = "A"
        Cells(1, 2).Value = grade
    Else
        grade = "Check"
        Cells(1, 2).Value = grade
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Would be helpful to describe what is your expected output instead of just writing _it's not returning correct result_

Comment: If i mention 1 to 49 any num in excel cell (1,1) then 'IF' condition should get executed, as num1(49) > (less then) 50 and cell (1,2) should be "B". And if num1 = 51 till 100 then 'ELSEIF' condition should get called and result should be in cell (1,2) is "A" , as the number is greater then 50 and less then equel to 100 and if i mention num1=more then 101 then 'Else' condition should execute.

Comment: Please don't tell us how your code should work, but what you're trying to achieve. What is the goal of your program ?

Comment: @KajalPrasad Could you please edit your last comment into the question.  It will make this question easier to read and therefore more likely to get answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `ElseIf` statement can never become true.

First you check if `num1` is bigger or equal than `50`:

```
If num1 >= 50 Then
  grade = "B"
  Cells(1, 2).Value = grade
```

Imagine if `num1` equals `49`, then the next `ElseIf` will get executed. This checks if `num1` is smaller or equal to `100`, but you know for sure this is always the case because if it would be bigger than `100`, the first `If` would have been executed.

The next thing is that it is checking if `num1` is bigger than `50`. Well, you know for sure it is not because this was already checked in the first `If` statement.

I think this is what you want:

```
Private Sub Sheet2_1()
  Dim num1 As Integer
  Dim grade As String

  Randomize Timer
  num1 = Int(Rnd * 100)

  Cells(1, 1).Value = num1

  If num1 <= 50 Then
    grade = "B"
    Cells(1, 2).Value = grade

  ElseIf num1 > 50 And num1 <= 100 Then
    grade = "A"
    Cells(1, 2).Value = grade

  Else
    grade = "Check"
    Cells(1, 2).Value = grade

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: hi moffeltje, thx for your try. senario is little different which i am looking for. Let me explain you.     If i mention 1 to 49 any number (in excel cell (1,1)) then 'IF' condition should get executed, as num1(49) > (less then) 50 , In this case result in cell (1,2) should be "B". And if num1 = 51 till 100 then 'ELSEIF' condition should get called and result should be in cell (1,2) is  "A" , as the number is greater then  50 and equel to 100  and if i mention num1=more then 101 then 'Else' condition should execute.

Comment: `>` is not "less than" it is "greater than". Did you test my code?

Comment: o yes, thank i changed the operator (less then , greater then) in IF & Elseif , now it is showing correct result in cel (1,2). thank you moffeltje